# array_filter multidimentional, how check two conditions in sub-index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have a problem, i have this code:

```
$pass = array_filter($var, function($first){

    return $first['Data']['Show'] == true && !empty($first['Data']['Botones']) ? array_filter($first['Data']['Botones'], function($second){
        return $second['Visible'] == true;
    }) : 1; 

});


echo json_encode($pass);
```

and the first array_filter works, but the array is multidimentional and if i have:

```
[0] = Array(
    "Title" => "Home", 
    "Show" => true,
    "Buttons" => Array(
        Array("Title" => "Sub-Home", "Visible" => false),
        Array("Title" => "Sub-2-Home", "Visible" => true),
    )
)
```

the code shows all Buttons of sub-menu, how i can fix this?

Comment: those indices that you use in your array and inside the actual function differ. `Buttons != Botones`